# trying to convert a tree to a list in c++

Tags: c++, list, recursion, tree, inorder

I am trying to convert a tree to a list inorder. Here 's the code I have so far.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using std::cout;
 using std::endl;
 using std::ostream;

class Tree{
public:
Tree(): root(nullptr), list(nullptr){
}
~Tree(){
    delete_postorder( root); root = nullptr;
    delete list;             list = nullptr;
}
void add(int d){
    if (root==nullptr)
        root = new Node(d);
    else
        add_inorder(root, d);
}
friend ostream& operator <<( ostream& o, Tree& t){
    o << "Inorder traversal:   ";
    t.print_inorder(o, t.root);
    o << endl;
    return o;
}
void convert_to_list( ostream& o ){
    o << "Converting to a list ... ";
    delete list; list = nullptr;
    list = list_inorder( root );
    /*
     * Print list
     */
    for (LNode* p = list; p != nullptr; p=p->next)
        o << p->data << " ";
    o << " done!" << endl;
}
   private:
class Node{
public:
    Node(int d): data(d), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {
    }
    ~Node() {
        delete left;  left = nullptr;
        delete right; right = nullptr;
    }
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};
Node* root;

void add_inorder(Node* t, int d){
    if (d <= t->data)
        if (t->left == nullptr)
            t->left = new Node(d);
        else add_inorder(t->left, d);
    else
        if (t->right == nullptr)
            t->right = new Node(d);
        else add_inorder(t->right, d);
}

void print_inorder( ostream& o, Node*t ){
    if (t==nullptr)
        return;
    print_inorder(o, t->left);
    o << t->data << " ";
    print_inorder(o, t->right);
}
void delete_postorder(Node* t){
    if (t== nullptr)
        return;
    delete_postorder( t->left );
    t->left = nullptr;
    delete_postorder( t->right );
    t->right = nullptr;
    delete t; t=nullptr;
}
class LNode{
public:
    int data;
    LNode* next;
    LNode(int d): data(d), next(nullptr){
    }
    ~LNode(){
        delete next; next = nullptr;
    }
    void append(int d){
        LNode* p = this;
        for (; p->next != nullptr; p=p->next)
            ;
        p->next = new LNode( d );
    }
};

LNode* list;
LNode* list_inorder(Node* t){
    if (t==nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    LNode* left = list_inorder( t-> left );
    LNode* right = list_inorder( t->right );
    if (left == nullptr)
        return right;
    if (right == nullptr)
        return left;
    /*
     * Find last node in "left" and append right to it.
     */
    LNode* p = left;
    for (; p->next != nullptr; p=p->next) ;
    p->next = right;
    return left;
}

  /*    void list_inorder(Node* t){
    if (t==nullptr)
        return;
    list_inorder( t-> left );
    if (list==nullptr)
        list = new LNode( t->data );
    else
        list->append(t->data);
    list_inorder( t->right );
}
    */
    };



   int main(){
Tree t;
int data[] = { -2, 3, 10, -21, 35, 3, 85, -2, 100};

for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
    t.add( data[i] );p

cout << t << endl;

t.convert_to_list( cout );

cout << "Done!";
     }
```

The commented list_inorder is a recursive way to convert the tree in inorder to a list and it works. The other list_inorder method( uncommented one) is the one I am work on. For some reason, the other list_inorder does not work. I am trying to return the a pointer pointing to the first node in the converted list. So, I can run through the list and print the elements out in the convert_to_list method.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you implement your own list instead of using e.g. [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)?

Comment: A `Node` has `left` and `right` child. From where do you get `next`?

Comment: thats a requirement that I cannot use the list from std library

Comment: which node do you mean. All the node objects have left and right only. The one with next is LNode object

Comment: LNode is used for the list. Node is used for the tree-All the nodes in the tree.

Comment: Have you tries making a small tree, and then step though the code line by line in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the logic a bit, since you are not returning any value.  By changing the if statement as below, this allows the recursive calls to exit properly.  (Also, change how you call it in the convert function `list_inorder( root );`)

```
void list_inorder(Node* t){
    if (t!=nullptr)
    {
        list_inorder( t->left );
        if (list == nullptr)
            list = new LNode( t->data );
        else
            list->append(t->data);
        list_inorder( t->right );
    }
}
```

```
Inorder traversal:   -21 -2 -2 3 3 10 35 85 100 
Converting to a list ... -21 -2 -2 3 3 10 35 85 100  done!
Done!
```